# call then delay if empty failing in PhP

Tags: php, http

I am trying to make an API call for a new ip address just provisioned so the fail rate from being impatient is high.
So I am trying to make the call and if the response is empty, pause for 5 second then try again.
But $label !== 'Freetoo' is failing false/executing even if string exist.

output:

we need to wait a little longer for your server to get ready 
we need to wait a little longer for your server to get ready 
107.191.60.48
string(7) "Freetoo" we need to wait a little longer for your server to get ready

```
function getlist(){
        $list_output = file_get_contents('https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/list?api_key=www');
        return $list_output;
}

//var_dump($server_output);

echo '<br><br>';
$output = getlist();
$decoded = json_decode($output, true);

foreach($decoded as $value) {
        $ip = $value['main_ip']; // string not array
        $label = $value['label']; // string
        if($label === 'Freetoo') {
        // do something
                echo $ip; // and others that you have to do
                //break;
                echo '<br>';
                var_dump($label);
        }else if($label !== 'Freetoo'){
                echo 'we need to wait a little longer for your server to get ready <br>';
                //sleep(5);
                $output2 = getlist();
                $decoded2 = json_decode($output2, true);
                foreach($decoded2 as $value2) {
                        if($label === 'Freetoo'){
                                echo 'it made it this time<br>';
                                echo $ip;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

How do I initiate a http request and pause of the request is empty?

Comment: check what is the content of `$label` before you do `if else`. just for debugging purposes.

Comment: @UserProg  the string exist. The first thing I did was var_dump it.